# OpenVpn troubleshooting

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, unix, troubleshooting

I run a VPN with Openvpn on a Debian 8 server. It works kinda well.

Sometimes (once a month or every 3 weveks) the tunnel stops running and I have to reboot the server to be able to connect to the vpn.

I've looked in syslog, messages etc but couldn't find any relevant information about why the service stops.

Do you have any idea on where to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `log <file>` directive to force openvpn to use `<file>` as it's log. This makes it easier to see what is happening. I would (if necessary) also increase the log verbosity using the `verb` directive. Then, wait and see what happens and take action ass appropriate.